# Count of rows containing null values in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

Consider a pyspark dataframe for example

```
columns = ['id', 'dogs', 'cats']
vals = [(1, 2, 0),(None, 0, 1),(5,None,9)]
df=spark.createDataFrame(vals,columns)
df.show()
+----+----+----+
|  id|dogs|cats|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|   0|
|null|   0|   1|
|   5|null|   9|
+----+----+----+
```

I want to write a code which returns 2 as the number of rows containing null values

Comment: This question is too broad for this site.  Take a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some help on asking

Answer (score 2):

`df.subtract(df.dropna()).count()`

The `df.dropna()` returns a new dataframe where any row containing a null is removed; this dataframe is then subtracted (the equivalent of SQL `EXCEPT`) from the original dataframe to keep only the rows with nulls in them.

This is obviously not as pretty as if you were only looking at a single column, but this is the simplest way I know to do this when all columns are involved.

Comment: This is what i'm doing now, wanted a more efficient way to do it.